# Why are duplicate UUIDs being generated from python on GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, celery, uuid

I am facing this weird issue. Some (5%) of my celery tasks are silently being dropped.

Doing some digging in celery logs, I found that in some cases, same task IDs get generated for different tasks. Naturally, any new task overwrites an existing task with the same task ID; causing the old task to silently drop (if it wasn't executed).

In a span of 1.5 hours, the same UUID was generated 3 times. I did some random sampling and this turned to be the case on the same machine, in a short span (1-2 hours). The server generates around 1 million UUIDs a day. A minuscule number with 7 digits compared to a number with **38 digits**- the number of possible UUIDs.

I am running python 3.6, and celery 4.4.2 on a Linux VM.

Celery uses python's `uuid.uuid4`: [Reference](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/kombu/utils/uuid.html)

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Is there a bug in a version of python (or the linux kernel), some configuration issue, or a hardware/VM bug? *All scenarios seem very unlikely.*

**Update:**

The VM is a standard Google Cloud Plaftform compute instance running ubuntu 18 LTS.

Comment: Interesting. [`uuid4` just calls `os.urandom`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1642c0ef750f96664a98cadb09301d492098d2fb/Lib/uuid.py#L713) for its source of bytes, so I'm guessing it's a platform-specific issue with randomness?

Comment: Do you have any details of how the VM interacts with the underlying hardware? I'm curious where the randomness is actually coming from in such a setup.

Comment: @bnaecker I added more info to my question

Comment: People have seen uuid4 collisions in the past (https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80), but in this particular case reached a conclusion that it was a system issue

Comment: What is your visibility timeout?

Comment: @DejanLekic its 8 hours (`8 * 60 * 60`). Does it have any effect?

Comment: If the task is not ACKed within that time it will be redelivered and picked by another worker possibly causing this behaviour... Are you using `acks_late=True`?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out why but I implemented a workaround.

I monkey patched `uuid.uuid4`. For some reason I was unable to do the same for `celery.utils.uuid` or `kombu.utils.uuid`.

I made a very simple random number generator that concatenates the system nano time, and the hostname, and generates a UUID:

```
def __my_uuid_generator():
    time_hex = float.hex(time.monotonic())[4:-4]  # 13 chars
    host = hex(abs(hash(socket.gethostname())))[2:]  # 16 chars
    hashed = bytes(f'{time_hex}{host}', 'ascii').hex()[:32]  # always a 32 chars long hex string
    return uuid.UUID(hashed)

# Monkey patch uuid4, because https://stackoverflow.com/q/62312607/1396264. Sigh!
uuid.uuid4 = __my_uuid_generator
```

Comment: Just so you know - it IS possible to get duplicate tasks running, and it is not because of UUID collisions, but because of what I wrote in the comment above...

Comment: @DejanLekic there were duplicates in a timeframe < visibility timeout. Not set `acks_late`. Also, after implementing the above, I didn't get duplicates.